# How to manage multiple submit button in my case in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner to MVC, I am using MVC 5

**_Layout.cshtml code**

> `_Layout.cshtml` has navbar, it contains **Logout, More button** if user already loggedin, Also, it will render body part(`Index.cshtml`)

```
//Navbar
@if (ViewBag.name != null)
{
    <input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" formaction="Logout" value="Logout" id="btnLogout" />
}
else{
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login & Signup</a>
}
<input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" formaction="More" value="More" id="btnMore" />
//body
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()    //Index.cshtml
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml**

> `Index.cshtml` it has some links and also some buttons and anchor links, and **it will call partial view (`_Login`)**

```
@using TestProject.Models
@model ViewSignInAndSignUp 

//some html code
<input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" formaction="Action1" value="Action1" id="btnAction1" />
<input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" formaction="Action2" value="Action1" id="btnAction2" />

@Html.Partial("_Login")   //partialview
```

**_Login.cshtml**

> `_Login.cshtml` this one partial view, if user visit any links, this partial view will popup to request the user to make login. This partial view buttons are working

```
@model TestProject.Models.SignIn
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerSignIn", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.userName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtLogin" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword", @type = "password" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Login" id="btnLoginSubmit" />
}
```

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logout(string submitButton)
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult More(string str1)
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(string str1)
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action2(string str1)
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Now, How can I manage all the buttons from `_Layout.cshtml, Index.cshtml, _Login.cshtml(Partial view)`

**Note**

> my login button is working, but, logout, more, action1, action2 buttons are not working

Comment: A **submit** button submits **a** `form`. So it's unclear if your issue is really just styling elements to "look" like buttons, or multiple forms for each button.

Comment: @Edsf I just a have to pass some parameters for each button like login button(login button will pass parameter username and password). In the same way I have to perform other buttons

Comment: You have to wrap each input `type='submit'` in its own form if you want to call separate controller actions.

Comment: As the above comment states, or, you can create whatever payload you want in an AJAX post.

Comment: @msmissile you mean like how I created for Login, have to create like this to logout `@using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Home"))`??

Comment: @Edsf sorry, i don't want to use ajax, I just want to know how to manage multiple partial with multiple buttons on each partial. that is my target

Comment: @Liamneesan if you don't want to use AJAX, all of your partials must have a form for it's respective submit button. As it was said before, a SUBMIT button SUBMITS a FORM, there's no way to bypass this unless you code your own posts on javascript

Comment: Let's try this: _each_ of your buttons must have its **own `form`**. That way each `submit` `button` only submits the form data it is responsible for.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a form for the logout?  Same could easily be achieved by redirecting using an anchor tag.  Using a form here is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" formaction="Logout" value="Logout" id="btnLogout" />
```

with this

```
<a href="Account/logout">Logout</a>
```

Replace the href with the logout endpoint for your application if different than stated above.  Remove any form pointing you to the logout endpoint also as it is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button submits the form using action URL defined in `<form>` tag, if you want to use multiple submit buttons then you need to wrap them inside multiple forms with different values of `action` attribute.

However, there's no need to use multiple submit buttons for those action methods, because redundant `<form>` tags are inefficient. You may just use `@Html.ActionLink()` helper to call them like this (and then use styling for those links to look like a button):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home", null, new { @class = "dropdown-item", @id = "btnLogout" })
```

If the action contains parameter(s), you should add [`routeValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) like example below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action1", "Action1", "Home", new { str1 = "SomeValue" }, new { @class = "dropdown-item", @id = "btnAction1" })
```

And change HTTP method to `GET` because `ActionLink` helper generates anchor `<a>` tag with `href` attribute which should use `GET` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    // some coding
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The same treatment should be applied to `More`, `Action1` and `Action2` action methods as well.

Further reference:

[ActionLink helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)